# Finding out whether two ranges (one of them is sorted) have a common element

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote the following code that does it:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::vector<int> sortedRange;
// ...
bool hasCommonElement = 
    std::any_of(begin(vec), end(vec),
                std::bind(std::binary_search, begin(sortedRange), end(sortedRange), _1));
```

The compiler is complaining that it cannot find out which overload of binary search I mean. Do you have any other elegant solution? Or a good reason why it does not compile?

**Edit**

- I do know I can use a lambda. But here the bind seems more elegant (if I had generic lambdas, it would be great! But I don't).
- I do know that I can qualify the iterator type: `binary_search<std::vector<int>::iterator>`. But it is even less elegant.
- I know I can also do it by sorting "vec" and using set_intersection. But this is more complicated too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a lambda instead of `bind`:

```
bool hasCommonElement = any_of(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](int x) {return binary_search(begin(sortedRange), end(sortedRange), x);});
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid "polluting" it with types and different kinds of braces. This time lambda seems less elegant.
However, it seems I don't have much choice :/

Comment: @Alex I don't see how the other approach with `std::bind`, `std::binary_search<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>` and `std::placeholders::_1` is a cleaner, more readable and easier to understand solution than this one with the lambda.

Comment: You might wish to mention that polymorphic lambdas will eliminate the need for spelling out the type (`int`) of `x`. This will make this solution safe, should the type of `x` change.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. The binary_search is a template (which parameters are not deduced) and you need to qualify the placeholder:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main( {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<int> sortedRange;
    bool hasCommonElement =
        std::any_of(
            begin(vec), end(vec),
            std::bind(
                std::binary_search<std::vector<int>::iterator, int>,
                begin(sortedRange),
                end(sortedRange),
                std::placeholders::_1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did qualify the placeholder.. just not in this code sample here. Will fix :)

Anyway, it seems that in this case a lambda will be more elegant, if I need to directly specify the iterator type and it cannot be deduced.